# Boto Script for user deletion with time constraint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, boto

I am working on a boto script that will delete the user after a time period of 20 minutes. I am not able to figure out the approach for the solution.So far I can delete the user without a time period constraint using this script.

```
    import boto3
    import sys
    import json
    import datetime
    import dateutil
    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    response = iam.remove_user_from_group(
        GroupName='GoodGroup',
        UserName='GoodUser'
    )
    response = iam.delete_user(
        UserName='GoodUser'
    )
```

Comment: What are you using to trigger the "20 minutes" part? When does the 20 minutes start? Can you just run a shall script that calls `sleep 1200` and then runs the Python script?

Comment: I need to have a python script for deleting the user. 20 minutes will start as soon as the user is created. I want to include the delete user in the same as the python script for creating user.

Comment: Simply insert a Python [`sleep`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm) command between the create and the delete.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the user with a `get_user()` call, and use the `CreateDate` and current time to figure out the delta.  Use an if statement to remove the user if the delta is greater than or equal to 20 minutes.

#### References

- [IAM get_user](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_user)
- [Check if datetime is older than 20 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398205/how-to-check-if-datetime-is-older-than-20-seconds)